# Service Worker - no postMessage method available on controller

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a question on service worker and client communication. I was looking at this post and other blogs, but none of them working.I'm getting an error in Chrome latest version.

[Communcation between service worker and web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607563/communcation-between-service-worker-and-web-page)

I tried using `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({'command': 'trimCaches'});`

but i'm getting an error in Chrome, *Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined*

. Further investigation shows there is no postMessage method available in controller. Can anyone help me out.

My requirement is to send some message/data to service worker.

Answer (score 1):

This error, ***"Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined"***, tells that there is no serviceWorker available in navigator. In other words, no Service Worker has been registered on the page. This could be because there was none and the page was just loaded or there was an error during the registration. I'm not completely sure what you mean by further investigating the controller since the error message clearly says there's no serviceWorker in navigator thus there *cannot be a controller to investigate*.

I guess when you call navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage() the registration is NOT complete. I suggest that you register an SW and include the message receiving logic in the SW script. Then, after loading the page AND checking from the Dev tools that the SW has really registered, you play around with the postMessage API in the browser's console.

Another way to make sure you only call the postMessage on controller is to include that piece of logic in the serviceWorker.register() Promise handler.

This might be of help for you, too https://serviceworke.rs/message-relay.html

Comment: Great answer, building on this slightly is Jeffs answer to a similar question I posted not too long ago. I think it might be some help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173712/best-practice-for-instant-claim-of-a-page-by-service-worker